# Excel VBA active windows directory path and rename the file

Tags: vba, windows, excel, internet-explorer, directory

i am making a script that downloads file's from the internet.
I got it working to the part where it downloads the file and opens it in the windows directory.

I need to know where that directory location is, so i that the name can be changed and saved to a other location.

```
ie.document.getElementByID("FactuurnummerTextBox").Value = Decl


ie.document.getElementByID("zoekenOpDeclaratiedetailsButton").Click

Do While .busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do While .readystate <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.getElementByID("btnSelectDeclaratie").Click

Do While .busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Do While .readystate <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.getElementByID("DownloadImage").Click

Do While .busy
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.Focus

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

ie.document.Focus


ie.findWindowEx(ie.document, 0, "View Downloads - Internet Explorer",       vbNullString).Click

SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "~", True
```

Then the save as window appears.

( i am sorry for the send keys.... i have a problem with the notification bar of the downloader)

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. Show the code that you have so we'll be able to see what it is you're doing.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking?  If your downloading into the Windows directory (which you should not be doing) and you want to change that, it will depend on how you are downloading the file, if you want the windows path you can call environ$("WINDIR")

Comment: **A)** Post your code. Not only is it helpful, it's part of the requirements mentioned in the [help]. **B)** If you're automating IE, then fire up IE and look at where the default download directory is, that's where it will be putting your files

Comment: Thank you for your reactions, i posted the last part of the code.

Comment: I need to be able to operate in the pop up window (the save as window).

Comment: The reason that i have to do this, this way. is that i am dealing with a secure server, that does not let me change the IE settings.